# Angularjs animate - disable for some ngRepeat

Tags: angularjs, ng-animate

Is it possible somehow completely disable animation for some ngRepeat directive usage?

I don't have any animations defined yet, but when ngAnimate module is loaded, automaticaly delays removing DOM elements from ngRepeat..

Comment: I am having similar issues. Which version are you using?

Comment: latest in time I was asking.. currently I disabled animation and let problem solve by my "future Me" :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The good folks from the AngularJS team confirmed this as a bug that has been fixed in version 1.2-RC3: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/4789